# Appending element into the list of list overrides the entire list

Tags: python

Code is as shown below :

```
s = [[]] *4
s[0].append(1)

print(s)
```

it gives me output :

```
[[1],[1],[1],[1]]
```

but i want output like this :

```
[[1],[],[],[],[]]
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: the reference remains the same so the operation on 1st row corresponds to  all the row, create the 2D list using list comprehension as `[[] for _ in range(n)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `[[]] * 4` to create four lists. In this case, you are just creating one list and four references pointing to it.

So you should use `[[] for _ in range(4)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional info to Sraw's reply:

```
>>> t = [[]] * 4 
>>> t
[[], [], [], []]
>>> id(t[0]) == id(t[1]) == id(t[2]) == id(t[3])
True
>>> l = [[], []]
>>> id(l[0]) == id(l[1])
False
```

You get 4 references to same list. That's why adding an element to any of the references show up in the others.